# How to reduce redundant codes when overwriting function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have to overwrite a function in my project.
Here is the `original.js` file:

```
lib.func = function(a){
     //original logic
}
```

And this is `A.html` where I overwrite `func` function:

```
<script src='original.js'></script>
<script>
     var original = lib.func;
     lib.func = function(a){
         //overwrite to modify a
         a.replace(c, 'new');
         original(a);//call original function
     }
</script>
```

And this is `B.html` where I replace `a` with **another string d**:

```
<script src='original.js'></script>
<script>
     var original = lib.func;
     lib.func = function(a){
         //overwrite to modify a
         //***********Different replacement source********
         a.replace(d, 'new'); 
         original(a);//call original function
     }
</script>
```

My question is:
Is there a way to put this overwrite logic in a file and I can use it in both `a.html` and `b.html`?

Comment: is there any other change other then replaceing `c` and `d`?

Comment: @OAD No, only modifying parameter `a` with different values.

Comment: You are trying to override logic based on context. You will have to supply some context when you invoke lib.func(a). Why do you need the call to be exactly like the original? Can you take in a context object?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add that to the original function, and pass a string param. You can execute the original function without the extras by calling an `if` on the string param

```
lib.func = function(a, b){
    if (b) a.replace(b, 'new');
    // original logic
}
```

This way you can reuse the method anywhere and dynamically choose the replacement as needed.
**EDIT**: Just to be clear, if you don't pass the second parameter then the method will execute exactly as it would before, but when you do pass a second parameter, the if statement will catch it and replace.

Comment: Thanks, but my code will still call `lib.func(a)` with only one parameter. Take `require.js` as an example. I overwrite `require.load` function, but I will not call `require` in  a new way.